# how to display information after action class executed dialog box in struts2

Tags: struts2

Suggest me how to display information after action class execute completed her i am developing form submitting application 3 form in html first on submitted after one ID are generator this ID how to display end user they can note dowe

Comment: I'd consider going through a basic Struts 2 tutorial. Nutshell: view properties are exposed through action getter methods.

Comment: view pages in html format and i am using struts2 with hibernate In application are there 3 html form first form are submit and save in table after 2 form filling before one id are created How to display that id from end user i am try to dialog box but how to display that id from end user